# Does JavaScript automatically skip empty/bodiless functions?

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, optimization

**"tl;dr" included**

When trying to disable Logging so as to avoid spam once deploying, I used to do something like

```
if (isDebug)
    console.log(...);
```

but I felt like (or read online) this would slow the code overall because the condition would be evaluated each time (and I usually include a lot of these, and the functions are called often, either via loops, setIntervals or w/e).

As such, I now switched to simply "emptying" the functions using a custom logger like

```
function LOGGER_MODULE_FACTORY() {
  let current_log_level = "log";
  return {
    log: console.log,
    info: console.info,
    warn: console.warn,
    error: console.error,
    setDebug: function(logLevel) {
      current_log_level = logLevel;
      this.log = (logLevel === true || logLevel === "log") ? console.log : function () {};
      this.info = (logLevel === true || logLevel === "log" || logLevel === "info") ? console.info : function () {};
      this.warn = (logLevel === true  || logLevel === "log" || logLevel === "info" || logLevel === "warn") ? console.warn : function () {};
      this.error = (!logLevel) ? function () {} : console.error;
      return logLevel;
    },
    getCurrent_log_level: function () { return current_log_level; }
  }
}
```

Thinking that it would probably be quicker to run an empty function than evaluating an expression and it felt cleaner to write.

*I tried creating a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ybfs97k8/) to test my theory and compare performance but the values are often pretty random...*

**Edit**: [jsperf test](https://jsperf.com/conditionalvsbodiless)
Interesting results. "Chrome 64" 's results are from running in on Edge.

My reasoning relied on the fact that I read few things about CPUs and, apparently, they do things on their own in order to optimize the general run-time like, for instance, skipping useless operations: Say we have :

```
a = x
b = y
c = a + 3
```

The CPU would actually ignore the second line (or something... I am far from being an expert ahah, I just curiously read that fact).

Now, since we, on our browser, may access any globally declared variable at some point using the console, this cannot happen and so I felt I should simply ask online :

**tl;dr:**

Is calling an empty/bodiless function repeatedly (the pages I create basically run 24/7 on a dashboard) better, performance-wise than placing a condition in front of the original function (`console.log / info / warn / error`) ?

> Basically, you are asking which is faster f = () => {}; f() or flag = false; if (flag) f()

Comment: *"I felt like…"*, *"it would probably be…"* — Have you done some actual measurements whether this is a problem to be solved in the first place?

Comment: Not just CPU optimisation, but JavaScript engine optimisation too - they could easily be skipping entire blocks.  I would say though, if performing checks about log levels each time you log were indeed adversely affecting performance (because there's so many of them), you'd have so many logs to read through that they'd be virtually useless anyway.

Comment: Is this really a bottleneck? Technically an empty function should run faster than a function with a condition that would be evaluated and determines whether the function is run or not. However, I'd expect a browser to optimise away the difference. Still, replacing the function directly instead of hiding each call behind a flag should be way simpler to maintain.

Comment: Depends on whether your JS engine is better at inlining small function calls (including empty ones) or inlining constants into branch conditions.

Comment: Use jsperf.com to perform JavaScript benchmarks, not jsfiddle.com.

Comment: @deceze Nop, I'm asking out of curiosity. Maybe SO isn't the place for that ? As I said, the browser's console remembering all the logs was the main issue.

Comment: @Barmar I get a "429: RATE_LIMITED" when trying to access it for the very first time ahah Guess I'll try later but ty for the info (I initially ran the "benchmark" locally, only used JSFiddle to share it and not flood the post some more ^^).

Comment: @VLAZ the performance issues would occur mostly because the browser's console would keep the history of all the logs, which is quite a bit since the App runs 24/7

Comment: @JamesThorpe You're right. I made the App in a hurry with barely any testing etc... and used logs almost everywhere (stylizing them with info/warn/error) since the user would more often than not just say "it's broken" without any details ahah. Condition vs bodiless probably doesn't matter that much, the issues came from the browser keeping log history (see my comment to user VLAZ) and I prefer (and find it more maintainable) being able to remove/reassign the console functions.

Comment: @DixiPoowa the question of performance doesn't hinge on logs or no logs. My question is if an empty function vs an `if` is really a performance bottleneck you actually have. Basically, you are asking which is faster `f = () => {}; f()` or `flag = false; if (flag) f()` - *that* is the actual difference in performance I want to know about - is that an actual problem that needs optimising?

Comment: @VLAZ I should edit my question and just put your comment, it explains perfectly what I'm trying to find out too ahah Do you think I should ?

Comment: @DixiPoowa that was actually my question to you - is that really a problem you have? Because it seems like a premature optimisation and even then a microoptimisation, at best. As I said, I'd expect the runtime to optimise this for you anyway. So, unless that's actually an issue you currently experience, I think it would be very hard to say one way or another what is better - that might depend on your application structure itself and other factors. Again *if* there even is a measurable difference.

Comment: @VLAZ Ah no sorry then. I asked that out of curiosity. I had problem with flooding the logs so I looked for a way to disable them "smartly" but then wondered if using a flag before each log may be harmful (performance and maintainability) so I came here to ask. As many pointed out, the JS engine / browser **probably** already take care of that but I couldn't find articles about it (probably lacking the proper keywords like "inline" etc...) so I asked here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`isDebug` won't be evaluated at every execution, but the stored variable will just be read.

It would be different if it was `if (isDebug())`, in this case, every time the parser meets the statement, the function will be evaluated.

Obviously, reading the `isDebug` boolean variable will add some overhead, but this is not perceptible since reading and handling variable is the main purpose of a programming language, so the time required for reading a boolean will always be lower than any other statement in the code.

Reassigning the `console.log` function is not a bad idea, it could be useful for enabling or disabling the logs all in one point. But this is a solution for a different problem

Comment: According to the comments, it seems like there is not definitive answer as it could vary from one JS engine to another and/or browsers and, overall, probably has little impact anyway. Though your mentioning of "stored variable will just be read" makes me think that, instead of having a module calling the console functions, I could change the console's prototype straight away and do the flag check there. But then the function is called (_evaluated_, I think) every time and this may be the worst of boss worlds ahah Anyway, I guess my question was bad / too environment dependent to begin with.

Comment: @DixiPoowa Reassigning the `console.log` function won't need to evaluate the debug mode or not. It's an operation that's only made at application bootstrap. And I'm confident enough to say that the answer is definitive: the delay is so little that it doesn't matter at all